# send data over link to jquery function

Tags: jquery

what I want to do is

```
<a href="#" onClick="myjqueryfunc(data1,data2)"></a>
```

and in the jquery

```
 myjqueryfunc(variable1,variable2) { 
var  formData = "name=variable1&age=variable2"; 
$.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
    } }
```

so how can i do this ?

Comment: `'name=' + variable1 + '&age=' + variable2` is the most straightforward. But I'd rather use object notation here: `formData = { name: var1, age: var2 }`.

Comment: if you want to get data from form then use form.serialize()

Comment: could you write for me a complete example ? (of course except php page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" data-name="x" data-age="12" id="smth"></a>
```

in js

```
$("#smth").click(function(){
var name=$(this).data('name');
var age=$(this).data('age');

$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { var1 :name , var2:age  },
    ...
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't substitute variables inside strings, you would have to use string concatenation. But in the case of `$.ajax`, it's better to use an object.

```
myjqueryfunc(variable1,variable2) { 
    var  formData = {name: variable1, age: variable2};
    $.ajax({
        url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data with the data parameter

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { foo : 'bar', bar : 'foo' },
    ...
});
```

Comment: no, you misunderstood me. i want send data over link to jquery. not over jquery to other php page. i know how can i do it. but i cant send data over link to jquery.

Comment: The arguments to the function send the data to jquery.